# git - Get all new branches from remote

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-remote

I am working in an environment where every contributer basically uses their own branch for basically everything new they make. Therfore we get about 10 new branches a month. I do not know how the branches are going to be named but I'd still like to have them all. So far I am only able to track the branches I know the name of.
This basically translates as: I want to automatically craete all remote branches locally!

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

I use the GitHub GUI for windows and the console. I'm not afraid to use any of the two. But I would prefer a solution that uses simple methods of the GitHub GUI. If there aren't any I won't mind the normal console solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching from a remote will load *all* branches that exist on that remote:

```
git fetch <remote>
```

They will all be added as remote branches (basically `<remote>/<branchname>`) and won’t exist as local branches until you create them directly. This also helps to not clutter the `git branch` output, although you can still list all remote branches using `git branch -r`.

Comment: Isn't there a simple solution to create them all locally? I would prefer that!

Comment: @BrainStone Well, they do exist locally, they all have just the `<remote>/` prefix. Usually you wouldn’t really need all remote branches on a developer’s machine. But you can always just check them out. Furthermore, when having a branch `origin/foo`, you can just type `git checkout foo` and it will automatically create a local branch that tracks this remote branch (except if a local branch `foo` already exists of course).

Comment: I see. So is there a possibility to make GitHub display them? I mean I am mainly using this and is a thing of comfort.

Comment: Also consider what happens if you add a second remote (e.g., you might have both `origin` and `bob` where Bob has a different place he stores things).  Then, what happens if there's an `origin/cookie_recipe` *and* a `bob/cookie_recipe`?  You can make local tracking branches for both of them, but you cannot call both local tracking branches `cookie_recipe`.

Comment: I understand this concern. But this environment will never get a second remote. So this will never become a problem.

Comment: I don’t use the GitHub GUI, but I’m pretty sure that they offer a branch list (from the remote) somewhere and probably also have some quick “check this out” button.